# Update list of commit after push

Tags: git

In my application, i'm using `git push -u https://username:password@github.com/User/Repo <branch>` via childProcess.

The problem is that my graph which contain my list of commit isn't being updated after this push.

The reference of origin/branch isn't on the same level as the local one after the push. I think the problem come from using a url instead of origin, but i absolutely need to use one.

If someone know a solution or just a clue toward one, it could be a great help.

Comment: Did the `git push` exit with success (exit code zero)?

Comment: Problem is, you don't mention *why* you need to use the url. Also, the `-u` option is intended to be used once on a branch, but then its upstream is set and you (in most cases) don't need to change it, let alone reset it each time. For what reason can't you just `push <branch>`, or, more explicitly, `push <remote> <branch>`?

Comment: No errors were returned. 
And i use a url because i'm using it for an application and i need to put the username and password directly inside the push

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is you're using a URL rather than a named remote. Git needs a remote name in order to track a remote branch otherwise it simply doesn't know how to refer to it.

One work around would be to have the application set the remote URL before pushing.

```
git remote set-url <remote> <url>
git push <remote> <branch>
```

Then `<remote>/<branch>` will be updated.

---

But the real question here is why does the user have to specify the URL every time they push? A remote is something you're supposed to set up once and then use it by name... or not at all if an upstream is set on a branch.

> *use a url because i'm using it for an application and i need to put the username and password directly inside the push*

The username and password can be specified in the remote URL, though there are serious security implications; their password will be sitting in the clear on disk. The username and password should not change from push to push. If possible, change the application to set up a remote once, then use that remote to push.

The better option is to take the URL, username, and password separately. Set the remote using the URL. Store the username and password with [`gitcredentials`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html).